# how to set combobox value when choosing jtable data

Tags: java, combobox, jtable

```
public  void setForm(mhs m)
{ 

    String[] jurusan = {"TI","SI"};
    JComboBox<String> cjurusan = new JComboBox<String> (jurusan);
    String st;
    st = ((String)m.getJurusan()).toUpperCase();
    for(int i = 0; i < cjurusan.getItemCount(); i++)
    {
        String jur = ((String) cjurusan.getItemAt(i)).toUpperCase();
        if(jur.equals("SI"))
        {
            cjurusan.setSelectedIndex(1);                           
        }
        else
            {
                cjurusan.setSelectedIndex(0);
            }                   
    }   
    tnim.setText(m.getNim());
    tnama.setText(m.getNama());
    cjurusan.setBounds(110,70,90,20);
    add(cjurusan);
    } 
}
```

I want to set jcombobox's value according the data record in jtable, till now, I just get the data value at the first time, for second time the jcombobox's value is the same with last. please help. many thanks.

This is my sample image program : [screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RE3P.jpg)

Comment: Please post all pertinent code here as code-formatted text, and not as an image. None of us can copy your image into our IDE's and then compile and run it or modify it. An image of code does us little good. Best in fact if you could post a valid [sscce](http://sscce.org), a very small program that compiles and runs for us and that shows us your problem.

Comment: hi there, thanks for reply me, now the update, please check them. thanks

Comment: Thanks for the code, but again, a [mcve] would be better. You do have a problem here: `if(jur=="SI")`. Don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here. So instead do: `if (jur.equals("SI")) {`

Comment: oh ya mate, acctually I've already tried to use equals function also mate, and the result is the jcombobox is only firstime set the value of the data, when I have close one, and try other data, jcombobox cannot get current data. I think the problem is the event listener or something may be should be add in the program, but I don't know to use them, I'm already try them, but always get error.. :(